# how to set Container() height which has GridView child?? flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview, containers, height

i'm trying to make gif pictures gallery.
I wanna wrap gridview with container but container need to setting height.
how can I set Container()'s height relatively??
i wanna make to gridview.items grows, container height grows too.

[image]

red line is current container height i set.

```
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              height: 1000,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: GridView.builder(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: 6,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 3,
//                      childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
//                      crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
//                      mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                        value: videos[index],
                        child: VideoGifItem(),
                      )),
            ),
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping the `GridView` in a  `Container` ? You can set the `shrinkWrap` property of the `GridView` to `true` so it only takes up the space needed(based on the items).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need your `GridView` widget to take up space based on the number of items it has.

You can set the `shinkWrap` property of the `GridView` widget to `true`.

I added a demo using your code as an example:

```
Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
        width: double.infinity,
        child: GridView.builder(
          // set the shrinkWrap property to true
          shrinkWrap: true, // new line
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: 6,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
//                      childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
//                      crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
//                      mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
          ),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: videos[index],
            child: VideoGifItem(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: I've been looking for this. Thank you for the answer.